# How to change all keys of an animation at the same time?

Tags: animation

Not sure how to describe the question in more detail so instead I will give an example:

I animated a person sitting on a chair with his hand laying on the armrest. After I'm pretty much done with the animation, I decided that the armrest is too close to the person so I want to shift it a bit to the side. But that means I also have to move the wrist as well for the whole animation.
Is there a way to move the wrist for all keyframes in the animation equally so that it doesn't move back during the animation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move your bone a bit on the X location for example, select the bone in *Pose* mode, open the *Graph Editor*, enable the *Only Show Selected* option, unfold the tracks on the left, select the *X Location* track, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to make only this track selectable, and move up or down its curve (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>) as much as necessary (then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to bring the other tracks back):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But is there an easier way? Especially when I have to adjust more than one axis and maybe even the rotation, this way seems very inaccurate. 
It would be optimal if there was just a shortcut that switches the changes I'm about to do to the whole animation and not just to one key. But I guess there is no such shortcut?

Comment: it will be for the whole selected vertices of your curve, i.e. all the keyframes, not just for one key, but of course you'll need to change for all the transformations, first change the X location curve, then the Z rotation, curve, etc... I don't think there's any other way but I may be wrong